# How can I retrieve info with UrlFetchApp.fetch using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript

I have a question. I coded this piece of Google Apps Script, but I´m not getting the result that I´m waiting for

function getDataFromQuery(myId){

```
  var data;

  var sqlSlect = encodeURIComponent("select A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I,  J, K where A ="+myID+" ");     

  try{
         var fullQuery = "https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/spreadsheets/d/MY_GOOGLE_SPREADSHEET_ID/gviz/tq?tq="+sqlSlect+"&gid=THE_SHEET_WHERE_INFO_IS"; 

         Logger.log("<Full Query> "+fullQuery);     

         data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
            "https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/spreadsheets/d/MY_GOOGLE_SPREADSHEET_ID/gviz/tq?tq="+sqlSlect+"&gid=THE_SHEET_WHERE_INFO_IS");

         Logger.log("<Result> "+data.getContentText());

  } catch (e) {
     Logger.log("< Some error > " + e.toString());
  }

  return data;
```

}

¿Does anybody can give me an idea about what is happening?

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: what's the error log?

Comment: Hi friend, actually I´m not getting any erro, but, as the same time I´m not getting any result XD , this is what i got from console: 
[16-09-13 08:10:00:595 PDT] Ejecución correcta [30,242 segundos de tiempo de ejecución total]